# C double value round up

Tags: c, double

I have written a programm in C . Mostly, in the output is a point number. If I write "%.2lf" sometimes it round off but I would like that it allways round up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you obviously want to get 2 digits left behind the decimal dot you would need to transform the number before you use`ceil` and then transform it back:

```
val = ceil( val * 100.0 ) / 100.0
printf( "%.2lf\n", val );
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Include `math.h` if you don't have it already, and do:

```
ceil(myDouble)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ceil` function from `math.h`.